# Visual Studio 2012 still shows as Update 1 after installing ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I installed ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update on my VS 2012 on two machines now, and when I checked Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio, they still show as

"Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1"

and I'm wondering why it doesn't say Update 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1" is the version of VS2012 installed. ASP.Net and the Web Tools have their own version numbers.

[image]

[Here is some info](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-released.aspx) on VS20112 Updates (replacing Service Packs).